# Spring Data: native query with pagination: ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

My project uses `spring-data-jpa-2.7.1`.

I need to get from the database a list of chats (table `_chat`) whose participants (table `_chat_participant`) have a certain user. At the same time, I need to sort chats from by the date of the last message (table `_message`) or by the date the chat was created (field `created_at` in table `_chat`), if there are no messages in the chat yet. Plus I have to use pagination.

I created such a method with sql. It really works according to the condition described above. But without pagination.

```kotlin
@Query(
    value = """
        SELECT _chat.*
        FROM _chat
                 LEFT JOIN
             (
                 SELECT chat_id, created_at
                 FROM _message m1
                 WHERE number = (
                     SELECT MAX(m2.number)
                     FROM _message m2
                     WHERE m1.chat_id = m2.chat_id
                 )
                 ORDER BY created_at desc
             ) AS message ON _chat.id = message.chat_id
        WHERE _chat.id in (
            SELECT DISTINCT (chat_id)
            FROM _chat_participant
            WHERE participant_id = ?1
        )
        ORDER BY message.created_at DESC NULLS LAST, _chat.created_at DESC;
    """,
    nativeQuery = true
)
fun findAllByUserId(userId: String): List<ChatEntity>
```

I try to add pagination by adding `Pageable` argument to the method, but I get such error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"
  Position: 11
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
```

method with pagination (it has the same `@Query` as method above):

```
fun findAllByUserIdWithPagination(userId: String, pageable: Pageable): Page<ChatEntity>
```

where `pageable` is `PageRequest.of(page, limit)`. `page` = 1, `limit` = 5.

I tried to add `countQuery` `to @Query` but it didn't work too:

```
 countQuery = """
        SELECT count(DISTINCT (chat_id))
        FROM _chat_participant
        WHERE participant_id = ?1
""",
```

What am I doing wrong? I found in the [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native-1) that pagination can also be used with `nativeQuery`, and even the example looks similar to mine. But it seems like there is some other problem

Answer (score 1):

The most stupid mistake ever. The problem was due to `;` at the end of query value. After removing it everything worked fine.